# React: Carousel first slide goes to last slide

Tags: reactjs, typescript, carousel, styled-components, slide

I am using React-Typescript for my app. For styling, I am using [styled-components]. I have made one custom Carousel image and it works fine. but I want when the slide will go the last picture it will go like this `[1][2][3][4][1]` but right now it behaves like this `[1][2][3][4]`. I want Carousel like [Bootstarp](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/). But my logic does not work.

I share my code in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/carousel-m1wbx?file=/src/carousel.tsx).

**This is my app component where arrays of image pass to the carousel component**

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Carousel from "./carousel";

export const imgUrls = [
  `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1455849318743-b2233052fcff?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60`,
  `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60`,
  `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60`,
  `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60`
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Carousel slides={imgUrls} autoPlay dots />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**This is my Carousel component**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, memo, useCallback } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export interface ICarousel {
  children: JSX.Element[];
  currentSlide?: number;
  autoPlay?: boolean;
  dots?: boolean;
  interval?: number;
  arrow?: boolean;
  slideTest?: number;
}

const IMG_WIDTH = 320;
const IMG_HEIGHT = 700;

export default memo(
  ({
    autoPlay = false,
    dots = false,
    interval = 2000,
    arrow = false,
    slideTest,
    slides // This is my props which is coming from parent,
  }: ICarousel) => {
    const [savedSlides, setSavedSlides] = useState([]);
    const [currentSlide, setSlide] = useState(0);
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(autoPlay);
    const timer = useRef<any>(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
      setSavedSlides(
        slides?.map((slide, index) => {
          return (
            <CarouselSlide key={slide}>
              <img
                key={slide}
                src={slide}
                alt={`Example of mobile application ${index}`}
                style={{
                  borderRadius: `20px`
                }}
              />
            </CarouselSlide>
          );
        })
      );
    }, [slides]);
    // console.log(savedSlides);
    // console.log(savedSlides.length);

    const handleSlideChange = useCallback(
      (index: number) => {
        // IN here I made the condition but it does not work what I am expecting .
        // I want the first will go all the way to last slide
        setSlide(
          index > savedSlides.length - 1
            ? 0
            : index < 0
            ? savedSlides.length - 1
            : index
        );
      },
      [savedSlides]
    );

    const createInterval = useCallback(() => {
      timer.current = setInterval(() => {
        handleSlideChange(currentSlide + 1);
      }, interval);
    }, [interval, handleSlideChange, currentSlide]);

    const destroyInterval = useCallback(() => {
      clearInterval(timer.current);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (autoPlay) {
        createInterval();
        return () => destroyInterval();
      }
    }, [autoPlay, createInterval, destroyInterval]);

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>
          {currentSlide} - {savedSlides?.length}
        </p>
        <CarouselContainer
          onMouseEnter={() => {
            if (autoPlay) {
              destroyInterval();
            }
          }}
          onMouseLeave={() => {
            if (autoPlay) {
              createInterval();
            }
          }}
        >
          <CarouselSlides currentSlide={currentSlide}>
            {savedSlides}
          </CarouselSlides>
          {arrow ? (
            <div>
              <LeftButton onClick={() => handleSlideChange(currentSlide - 1)}>
                &#10094;
              </LeftButton>
              <RightButton onClick={() => handleSlideChange(currentSlide + 1)}>
                &#10095;
              </RightButton>
            </div>
          ) : null}
          {dots ? (
            <Dots>
              {savedSlides.map((i, index) => (
                <Dot
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => handleSlideChange(index)}
                  active={currentSlide === index}
                />
              ))}
            </Dots>
          ) : null}
        </CarouselContainer>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
);
// This is my styled components
const Buttons = styled.a`
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  position: absolute;
  &:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
`;

const RightButton = styled(Buttons)`
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  right: 0;
`;

const LeftButton = styled(Buttons)`
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  left: 0;
`;

const Dots = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
`;

const Dot = styled.span<{ active: boolean }>`
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  background-color: ${({ active }) => (active ? `red` : `#eeeeee`)};
`;

const CarouselContainer = styled.div`
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: ${IMG_WIDTH}px;
  height: ${IMG_HEIGHT}px;
  img {
    width: ${IMG_WIDTH - 20}px;
    height: ${IMG_HEIGHT - 50}px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  z-index: 1;
`;

const CarouselSlide = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  transition: transform 500ms linear;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
`;

const CarouselSlides = styled.div<{
  currentSlide: ICarousel["currentSlide"];
}>`
  display: flex;
  ${({ currentSlide }) =>
    ` transform: translateX(-${currentSlide ? currentSlide * 100 + `%` : 0})`};
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change greater than with greater and equal (>=) here

```
    setSlide(
      index > savedSlides.length - 1
        ? 0
        : index < 0
        ? savedSlides.length - 1
        : index
    );
```